# Bundle of Endomorphism of Line Bundle always trivial

Tags: general-topology, vector-bundles, line-bundles

Let $B$ a topologiocal space (I'm not sure if it should be nice enough for the following statement ... eg paracompact).

Let $L$ be a line bundle over $B$.

My question is how to see that the morphism bundle $\underline{Hom}(L,L)$ is a trivial bundle? (here $\underline{Hom}(L,L)$ means that it is fiberwise $b$ the space linear maps between one dimensional spaces $L_b$)

My attempts: Obvioulsy it suffice to show that there exist a non vanishing glocal section $B \to \underline{Hom}(L,L)$.

Intuitively I would guess that the map $b \to id_{L_b}\in Hom(L_b,L_b)$ should work. Is it ok or is it a bit more complicated and I have overseen a subtle detail?

Comment: Your proof is fine; the identity maps of the fibers constitute a nowhere-vanishing section of the bundle of endomorphisms. (But the title of your question is false; you need that the morphisms are between a line bundle and **itself**, not some other line  bundle.)

Comment: Why does it suffice to show there exists a non vanishing global section?